# Updating multiple documents with specific filters using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to update multiple documents in a mongoDB database using pymongo. I have this data:

```
data_to_be_updated = [
    {"sourceID" : 6, "source" : "test", "name" : "simon"},
    {"sourceID" : 8, "source" : "test", "name" : "greg"},
    {"sourceID" : 9, "source" : "test", "name" : "julie"},
    {"sourceID" : 10, "source" : "test", "name" : "john"}
    ]
sourceIDs = [6, 8, 9, 10]
```

I would like to update each of the elements in `data_to_be_inserted`, filtering them by their `sourceID`. I have tried using the `update_many` function, but it updates all documents matching a single filter. I could of course use a for loop like this:

```
for item in data_to_be_updated:
    collection.update_one({"sourceID": item["sourceID"]}, item})
```

The above method uses to many calls. How do i achieve the same in a single call to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bulk_write](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#mixed-bulk-write-operations). Something like this, depending on exactly what fields need to be updated:

```
from pymongo.operations import UpdateOne

data_to_be_updated = [
    {"sourceID": 6, "source": "test", "name": "simon"},
    {"sourceID": 8, "source": "test", "name": "greg"},
    {"sourceID": 9, "source": "test", "name": "julie"},
    {"sourceID": 10, "source": "test", "name": "john"}
]

result = collection.bulk_write([
    UpdateOne(filter={'sourceID': d['sourceID']},
              update={'$set': {'name': d['name'],
                               'source': d['source']}})
    for d in data_to_be_updated])

print(result.bulk_api_result)
```